# Scalability issues related to distributed tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I was running some experiments to test the scalability of distributed tensorflow. My goal is to check how is the speedup of using 4gpus on 2nodes (in total 8gpus) compared with using single gpu.

I chose ResNet as the network structure and modified the ResNet example code from the official model zoos (github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/resnet) to be the one can do distributed training.
In the experiments, ResNet 56 layers is used for training on CIFAR10 data set and the settings follow the original paper.

First thing I would like to ensure is by using Synchronous SGD (SyncReplicasOptimizer), 8 gpus can get a similar curve as 1gpu in terms of **epoch-to-accuracy** figure. I used the same effective batch size (i.e., `batch size = 1gpu's batch size/the-number-of-worker`) on the two experiments.

Please check the experimental figures

[image]

> tf-0: single gpu version
>
> tf-1: distributed version (2ps, 8workers)
>
> x-axis: #epoch (per one means going through the whole training data once)
>
> y-axis: accuracy of CIFAR-10 **testing data**

The single gpu (**tf-0**) result is similar to the original paper and the ones reproduced by many other people (e.g., http://torch.ch/blog/2016/02/04/resnets.html, https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack/tree/master/examples/ResNet, or more examples here https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks#third-party-re-implementations).

However, you can observe that **tf-1** (8gpus curve) has a very different pattern, which is not what I expected. My understanding of Synchronous SGD is that optimizer accumulate `#workers` gradients and then apply to the variables. So the procedure should be exactly the same as single gpu if the same effective batch size is set.

Interestingly, when I set #worker = 2 in the distributed version, the curve (**tf-2**) become close to the single gpu version. But 4gpus (**tf-3**) got closer to **tf-1**.

[image]

> tf-2: distributed version (2ps, 2workers)
>
> tf-3: distributed version (1ps, 4workers)

Here are some detail settings (basically follows the original paper):

> batch size=128, num_residual_units=9, relu_leakiness=0
>
> learning rate scheduler: 0.1 for 1-80 epoch, 0.01 for 81-120 epoch, 0.001 for 120-160 epoch

Environments:

> Tensorflow version: 0.12.1
>
> Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN: CUDA 7.5, cuDNN 5.1

The single gpu version code can be found [here](http://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/22036b6f44efeb648fe2b2b4551f2b982edf0f5f/resnet/resnet_main.py)

The code for distributed version can be found [here](http://gist.github.com/infwinston/d01721d9609eef4a38b8e5e57719b194) .

Does anyone has ideas why it got gradually worse when #workers increase? Thanks.

---

**Updated figure**

According to commit ecdee38a (I think v0.12.1 includes this commit), tensorflow seems to use **averaging** instead of **summing up** gradients calculated by each worker. so I tried the one with 4x learning rate in 4gpus case. But got a even worse result.

[image: experiments of modified learning rate]

> 1xlr: 1x learning rate (0.1/0.01/0.001)
>
> 4xlr: 4x learning rate (0.4/0.04/0.004)

Comment: Note that ecdee38a changes gradient aggregation from adding to averaging, so the learning rate for k workers needs to be multiplied by k to have the same result. Can you debug on toy example first (ie, minimizing x^2 for scalar x) to make sure things work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, earlier I realized this possible issue, so I've run the one with larger learning rate (multiplied by #worker). But I got a even worse result. Please check the figure of my updated post. And thanks for the suggestion, I'll try some toy examples later.

Comment: sync_replicas optimizer should be equivalent to using single-machine tensorflow with a larger batch